# Conditional formatting not applying correctly

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am currently trying to use conditional formatting to highlight a section where the time is equal to or between two values.

When ran as a standalone formula, it works no problem. Unfortunately, when used as conditional formatting, it does not.

---

The formula I am using is:

```
=(Mod($A2,1)>=TimeValue(indirect("fall22SCHEDULE!"&cell("address", $H$2)))) * (Mod($A2,1)<=TimeValue(indirect("fall22SCHEDULE!"&cell("address", $I$2))))
```

---

While I originally though that my issue was with the sheet reference, I created another condition in a separate cell to check that, and that formula works.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have also tried wrapping the formula in an `IF` statement (if the result was >0, return TRUE).

---

**Example Sheet**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yLT3L-DgiAeXE-H_m_wYHWvXjk7tyafroy2zBzYSNhM/edit?usp=sharing

- `G2:G50` contains the formula working as intended (and demonstrating how I expect the conditional formatting to be iterating through the cells)
- `H6` contains an example of the sheet reference working as intended within conditional formatting
- `B2:B50` contains the conditional formatting rule
- Editing is **on**

---

###### References

- **Formula**: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/73798637/conditional-formatting-for-time-period-based-on-forms-timestamp?hl=en
- **Sheet Reference**: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/106075950/google-sheets-referencing-another-sheet-for-conditional-formatting?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed `=`

```
=(Mod($A2,1)>=TimeValue(indirect("fall22SCHEDULE!"&cell("address", $H$2)))) * (Mod($A2,1)<=TimeValue(indirect("fall22SCHEDULE!"&cell("address", $I$2))))
```

[image]